# Top Questions of the Week #25

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 25 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about, it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is quickly becoming a big question. 8 hours in and 39 votes later, there are lots of comments and answers.

- [How far will you get with a 'rm -rf /'](https://superuser.com/questions/312769/how-far-will-you-get-with-a-rm-rf)

It would be easy to write about this one too, it can all be done from a virtual machine without 'rm -rf'ing someones machine.

Comment: Sounds cool! If you're interested in writing about this, go for it - even if it doesn't win QotW, that would be a cool blog post. If you do anything with a VM, just make absolutely certain that you don't have any of those virtual drives mapped to your real machine ;)

Comment: @nhinkle Oh the horror.. Going to install Fedora right now to test it out ;)

Comment: Even if this doesn't get QOTW, there's some amazing stories, videos, and other links/resources in that question (specifically, the comments + answers).  I've been browsing for over an hour and still more cool stuff to find!

Comment: I just did it... Was awesomely fun.

Comment: Note: this post is finished, and will go up Monday. Thanks Simon!!

Comment: No problem, thanks @nhinkle, had a great time writing it!

Answer (score 5):

*Re-post from last week*

---

That one's interesting as well, given that it is well asked and the answers reveal something which not everybody knows. One could write about administrative shares in more detail in the blog then.

> ### [Security Concern with my Windows 7 Box at Work](https://superuser.com/questions/311061/security-concern-with-my-windows-7-box-at-work)
>
> The group I'm in recently got new computers at work. They gave me a new computer and hooked up my old computer to the network for a week so I could take my time transferring necessary files/configs etc. The Support Guy said, "Just go to 'run' and type in \PCNAME\c$. So I did and, low and behold, there's my old C: drive. I thought to myself, "What a huge security issue. I'll just transfer everything quickly and then 'un-share' it." [...]

Comment: Very interesting topic. Slhck, would you be interested in writing about this perchance? I'm also going to ask Darth Android (he answered and has blogged for us before) if he's interested.

Comment: I'd love to, but I honestly don't know the first thing about Windows, so that post might end up being a bit lame. If Darth Android wants to, that'd be great! @nhi

Answer (score 3):

Another one which has gotten <s>over 9000!</s> over 1000 views already:

> ### [Determining if a hard drive has been removed and data copied from it?](https://superuser.com/questions/311809/determining-if-a-hard-drive-has-been-removed-and-data-copied-from-it)
>
> Is there a method or a tool that can detect if someone has separated
>   my hard drive from my computer, copied data from it, and returned it
>   back?
>
> I want to be sure that no one has done this without my knowledge, but
>   I'm not sure how to this.
>
> - Note:I use `Deep freeze` .

It would allow one to write about how to protect your drive physically, but also through software measures. Some very interesting ideas in the answers.